# php code replaces all 1's with nothing when writing to a txt document

Tags: php, text-files

So, my code was perfect for my website yesterday... Until I realized that no one's (1's) show up in the document!!! I've searched throughout the whole code and nothing seems to be wrong!

I don't know if it's a bug in PHP (5.3), or something.... It just has to get fixed!

Recap: All ones (1's)  will be erased from an unknown cause)

My code is here:

```
  echo "Please wait while we submit your recipe...";

  //getting form data
  $thedate = Date("d-m-Y_H:i:s");
  $title = $_POST['Title'];
  $description = $_POST['Descript'];
  $ingredients = $_POST['Ingredients'];
  $instructions =$_POST['Instructions'];
  $notes = $_POST['Notes'];
  $name = $_POST['Name'];

  //replacement for extra characters
  $title = str_replace("\'" && "\"", "" , $title);
  $description = str_replace("\'" && "\"", "" , $description);
  $ingredients = str_replace("\'" && "\"", "" , $ingredients);
  $instructions = str_replace("\'" && "\"", "" , $instructions);
  $notes = str_replace("\'" && "\"", "" , $notes);
  $name = str_replace("\'" && "\"", "" , $name);
  $title = str_replace("\\", "" , $title);
  $the_recipe_url="RecibaseWaitingList/".$thedate."--".$title.".txt";
  $the_recipe_url = str_replace("'", "" , $the_recipe_url);
  $the_recipe_url = str_replace("\"", "" , $the_recipe_url);
  $the_recipe_url = str_replace("?", "" , $the_recipe_url);
  $the_recipe_url = str_replace(chr(10), "_", $the_recipe_url);

  //bugs show up before or after this 
  echo '...';

    //Checking to see if all required fields are filled
    if($title !== '')
    {
        if($ingredients !=='')
        {
            if($instructions !=='')
            {
                          //writing to the file
                          $writetothefile = fopen($the_recipe_url, 'c');
                          fwrite($writetothefile, $name." submitted this recipe on ".$thedate." \r\n \r\n "); 
                          fwrite($writetothefile, "Title: ".$title." \r\n ");
                          fwrite($writetothefile, $description." \r\n ");
                          fwrite($writetothefile, " \r\n ");
                          fwrite($writetothefile, "Ingredents:\r\n".$ingredients." \r\n");
                          fwrite($writetothefile, " \r\n ");
                          fwrite($writetothefile, "Instructions: \r\n ".$instructions." \r\n ");
                          fwrite($writetothefile, "\r\n ");
                          fwrite($writetothefile, "Notes: \r\n" . $notes . "\r\n \r\n ");
                          fwrite($writetothefile, "Thank you ".$name." for submitting this recipe! \r\n \r\n When you're done with the recipe, just click the back button.");
                          fclose($writetothefile);

                          //echo's for the user to see      
                          echo '<br />Your recibase recipe url is <a href="' . $the_recipe_url . '">' . $the_recipe_url . '</a>.';
                          echo "<br />";
                          echo "<br />";                      
                          echo "Thank you for being so generous with your time and entering your recipe. We hope you enjoy using the rest of the site!< br />"; 
                          echo "<br />";                
                          echo '<a href="http://recibase.musicsuper.org/input.php">Click Here</a> to enter in another recipe.<br />';
                          echo "...and we're done!";
             }else{echo "Go back, and enter the <b><i>Instructions</i></b> of your recipe please!".'<br><br><a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">'.'<--- Go Back</a>';}
          }else{echo "Go back, and enter the <b><i>Ingredients</i></b> in your recipe please!".'<br><br><a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">'.'<--- Go Back</a>';}
      }else{echo "Go back, and enter the <b><i>Title</i></b> of your recipe please!".'<br><br><a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">'.'<--- Go Back</a>';
```

What is causing the 1's to disappear? And why is it happening?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

If you want to see the product of this code with a sample recipe run through it, go here: http://recibase.musicsuper.org/AllOfYourRecipes/RecibaseWaitingList/15-02-2013_13:38:17--Deer%20Liver%20Pate.txt

Comment: what the *censored* `"\'" && "\"",` is supposed to do? what was your intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem are the `str_replace`, in particular the `"\'" && "\""`. This statement is equivalent to `1`, and so your `str_replace` are effectively `str_replace(1, "" , $title);`.

You'll want to use an array instead, so the code will be

```
str_replace(array("\'", "\""), "" , $title);
```

This will replace all occurances of the elements of the array with the empty string, just as you intended.

Comment: Oh! I had no idea that was happening! I thought that it was replacing both! I will quickly go change that. Thank you for helping on this.

Answer (score 2):

`&&` is a logical operator.

`$title = str_replace("\'" && "\"", "" , $title);`

If you `&&` two strings which evaluation to (boolean) `true`, the result will be `true`. That converted back to a string is going to be `1`. So in effect you're removing all `1`s.

Answer (score 0):

I probably found your problem:

You cannot use this function like that:

```
str_replace("\'" && "\"", "" , $ingredients);
```

`("\'" && "\"")` is evaluated to `TRUE` as a boolean and to `"1"` as a string.

Pass an array to the function:

```
str_replace(array("\'", "\""), "" , $ingredients);
```